# Pros and Cons of Different Action/Turn Frameworks

Tags: combat, actions, game-design, action-economy

I would like to have a clearer understanding of the pros and cons of various frameworks of turn composition and action economies. That is, I would like to see the relative benefits and drawbacks of different ways game systems handle answering the question about what actions a character can take in a turn (and how many thereof, or how their efficiency is influenced by their number etc.).

Now, of course the lines between framework will not always be sharp, but I think I can post a (non-exhaustive) list of what seems like some of the common paradigms or families thereof, in the hopes that this will better scope the question. Also please note that for the sake of maintaining focus and preventing tangents, I'm **not** asking about systems of initiative (who goes first), nor about comparing systems with vs. without a way of increasing the number of allowed actions above the default.

## Freeform Composition / Build Your Own Turn

Games which give the players the basic ground rules for deciding which actions to fit into a turn, each turn. Often defence and movement are treated just as any other action you can take. Examples would be older books in the Storyteller / Classic World of Darkness (e.g. VtM 2e), where you can Split your dice pool into as many actions as you need and can afford to (e.g. into three actions for performing two swings of your tyre iron [attack] and one dodge [defence]), or Fallout PnP (where you get an allotment of Action Points, and actions cost some number thereof, and one AP is also the cost of moving 1m or boosting defence by a certain value, though 'default' defences are free).

This framework seems to be equally capable of supporting the assumption that everyone gets defences for free and the assumption that defences are actions like any other.

## Type-Specific Action Slots

Games where a turn usually consists of a certain number (either fixed or upgradeable) of 'slots' of specific types, e.g. one move action, one 'do your thing' action that can be used for a variety of things (attack, move again, do a noncombat action etc.), and one or two reflex actions (often used for defences if the system puts a limit on the number of defences). Sometimes a systems allows choosing between several different sets of slots. Examples would be Dark Heresy and Eclipse Phase.

This framework *also* seems to be equally capable of supporting the assumption that everyone gets defences for free and the assumption that defences are actions like any other.

## Turn Structure Templates

Games where a player chooses one of a limited, often rather specific sets of actions for a turn, often with specific modifiers baked in. My go-to example would be GURPS, where you can choose e.g. *Move and Attack* (full movement, poor attack, slightly compromised defence), *Move* (full move, no attack), *Attack* (single step move, normal defence, normal attack), *All-Out Attack* (half of maximum move, attack with a bonus of choice, no defence at all), *Committed Attack* (attack with a modest bonus, seriously compromised defence, one- or two-step movement), *Ready* (get a special non-attack action, no attack, one step of movement, and normal defence), and some others.

This framework seems imply a strict regulation of what defences a given turn action structure template includes, and I *think* it predisposes one to lean towards having a 'with defences' structure as the more default one.

## Other Frameworks

I'm sure there are other framework that are distinct from the above three, but I'm currently not able to think of an example I'm well-acquainted with nor a generalised description. A comparison of any such additional frameworks is also welcome if someone is open to including them in an analysis.

Comment: When you're asking for the "pros and cons" do you mean, well, all of them? Such as how the structure might effect all the following and more: "fun", simulationism/realism, time-requirement, complexity level, rigidity vs fluidity (open-ended-ness/variety of actions), etc...? Also what would you like to be done about systems where initiative is a significant part of your action economy (such as declaring your actions on your initiative count but they actually take place X initiative counts later based on what you want to do)?

Comment: In a perfect world, 'all of them' would be interesting to read, but I suspect that will go into the 'write a book for an answer' territory. So key pros/cons take priority over the completeness of the list. As for heavily initiative-dependent systems: if it *only* influences when things are done and not what/how many things can be done in a turn, then it's best not to delve that deep. If initiative actually affects *how many* actions can be done, I guess that makes initiative folded into the main turn pattern and thus on-topic (Shadowrun maybe, not sure?).

Comment: This question is too broad unless we know the objective against which the “pros and cons” are measured. If something doesn’t do what you want it to do that’s a big con even if it does things you don’t care about really well.

Comment: @DaleM If a car can drive 200mph but you only ever drive 60mph, that is still a pro. Whether or not someone cares about it doesn't stop it being a pro.

Comment: @jgn no, it's a con because I may not be willing to let my son use it.

Comment: @DaleM Different questions get different answers

Comment: @jgn my point exactly

Comment: @DaleM Right, so a fast car would be a pro, not a con. You don't need someone to tell you they don't have an untrustworthy son, there is no point in enumerating negatives.

Comment: @jgn everyone's son (or daughter) is untrustworthy - you are not a good parent if you unconditionally trust your children. A fast car for an inexperienced or reckless driver is a con, for a racing driver its a pro. Pros and cons are situational.

Comment: @DaleM I'm not sure where in OP's question it says they are a parent.